# When throwing a exception

Tags: c++

So I have this coding lab, which I am suppose to throw a exception. It works correctly however I am having some issues with my output. The point of this program is to convert from hexadecimal to decimal. If the hexadecimal string is not hexadecimal, it should output "Not a hex number". However right now I am getting both outputs "The decimal value for hex number is" and "Not a hex number", when I am trying to throw the exception.

```
kevinalvarez@Kevins-MacBook lab9 % g++ 16~1.cpp
kevinalvarez@Kevins-MacBook lab9 % ./a.out 
Enter a hex number: JKLDS 
The decimal value for hex number JKLDS is Not a hex number
kevinalvarez@Kevins-MacBook lab9 %
```

Instead what I want it to output is

```
Not a hex number
```

My code:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

// Converts a hex number as a string to decimal
int hex2Dec(const string& hex);
// Converts a hex character to a decimal value
int hexCharToDecimal(char ch);

//defining HexFormatException exception class
class HexFormatException: exception{
public:
    //overriding what method to return an error message
    const char* what(){
        return "Not a hex number";
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Prompt the user to enter a hex number as a string
    cout << "Enter a hex number: ";
    string hex;
    cin >> hex;
    //calling hex2dec method inside a try block
    try{
        cout << "The decimal value for hex number " << hex << " is " << hex2Dec(hex)
         << endl;
    }catch(HexFormatException& e){
        //in case if HexFormatException occur, printing error message.
        cout<<e.what()<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

int hex2Dec(const string& hex)
{
    int decimalValue = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < hex.size(); i++){
        //checking if current char is a digit or lower/upper case hex char
        if(isdigit(hex[i]) || (hex[i]>='A' && hex[i]<='F') || 
            (hex[i]>='a' && hex[i]<='f')){
            //valid
            decimalValue = decimalValue * 16 + hexCharToDecimal(hex[i]);
        }else{
            //if not valid, throwing HexFormatException
            throw HexFormatException();
        }
        
    }
    return decimalValue;
}

int hexCharToDecimal(char ch)
{
    ch = toupper(ch); // Change it to uppercase
    if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'F')
        return 10 + ch - 'A';
    else // ch is '0', '1', ..., or '9'
        return ch - '0';
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Call `hex2Dec` before the `cout` line.

Comment: store the output of `hex2dec` in a temporary variable before the `std::cout`, and then `std::cout` the temporary variable. That way the exception is thrown before anything gets `std::cout`ed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that no output is printed before the exception is thrown via

```
try{
   int dec = hex2Dec(hex);  // may throw
                             // .. if not print it
   cout << "The decimal value for hex number " << hex << " is " << dec << endl;
}
```

Comment: That worked however, I am getting a warning message when compiling stating "auto type specifier is a C++11 extension". I assume this is a issue with my compiler correct?

Comment: @KevinAlvarez yes thats an issue with your compiler. You should upgrade it.